# JW Player 5.5 not working in Firefox

Tags: firefox, html, jwplayer

I'm using JW Player 5.5 with the JW Embedder in Firefox 3.6 but can't see anything. The object tag has been put in but the video fails to display. Has anyone else found issues with this or is it something I'm missing?

Comment: Do you have a link to your test page?

Answer (score 1):

If you have Ad Blocker installed, try turning it off on your page.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the solution to the question above, but the problem sounds like the one I had. My issue was that Firefox 3.5 and 3.6 were showing a black screen where the video is supposed to be. The cause of this was the order of the modes I provided jwPlayer with.

I had type: 'html' first. After swapping and putting type: 'flash' first as I have it below, jwPlayer performed in all browsers including iPad.

```
modes: [
    { type: 'flash', src: '/js/libraries/dynamic/jw-player/player.swf' },  // flash comes first!
    { type: 'html5' }
],
```